# Django Returning Image Name

Tags: django

My app allows users to create pictures.

In my Picture Module class , i'm been returning the description of the Picture objects lately and If the user doesn't put a description . I get an error.

Is it possible to return the name of the image that the user uploaded for my Picture module? For Example images.jpg

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board,blank=False,null=False)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image
```

My views.py

```
 def PictureCreator(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PictureForm(request.POST , request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            picture = Picture(user=request.user)
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            if image:
                                 picture.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
                         description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            if description:
                                 picture.description = form.cleaned_data['description']

            board = form.cleaned_data['board']
            if board:
                                 picture.board = form.cleaned_data['board']
            picture.save()
    return render(request,'picture.html',{'form':PictureForm()})
```

Thank you for helping me

I changed this

```
        image = request.FILES['image']
        if image:
                            picture.image = request.FILES['image']
                    description = form.cleaned_data['description']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
image = request.FILES.get('image') //return image name
```

Comment: I changed image = form.cleaned_data['image'] to image = request.FILES['image'] and I still got the same error

Comment: My module is still the same but i just change the view.    image = request.FILES['image']
   if image:
                                picture.image = request.FILES['image']

Comment: Is this correct?   image = request.FILES.get('image')
   if image:
                                picture.image = request.FILES.get('image')